# How can I tell if the result of a float division should be a whole number?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to know if I get an integer or float after division.

```
if (5.4 / 0.8 ==integer)  // except something that would evaluate as true in this case

{

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other examples using the `Math` library are certainly better, but another way to do this would be to convert the values to `decimal` before doing the division (to let the conversion take care of the rounding), and then ensuring that there is no remainder when dividing the result by `1`:

```
private static bool DivisionIsInteger(double numerator, double denominator)
{
    return (decimal) numerator / (decimal) denominator % 1 == 0;
}
```

---

*Countdown to an **ouch** comment from @elgonzo begins...now*

Comment: Ouch! My comments are getting mentioned in answers now? What is the world coming to? ;-P

Answer (score 5):

One way to do it is to use `Mathf.Round` to find the closest integer to the result and `Mathf.Approximately` to compare that integer to the result:

```
float f1 = 0.5;
float f2 = 0.1;
float result = f1/f2;

if (Mathf.Approximately(result, Mathf.Round(result)) {
    Debug.Log("integer result");
}
```

Comment: From which assembly does one obtain the `Mathf` class?

Comment: It's a part of the [Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d) engine

Answer (score 4):

Floating point number calculation comes with the precision problem.
For example, `0.3 / 0.1` equals to 2.9999999999999996, not 3.
In order to make a comparison, you'll need to round them and check if the difference is acceptable.

```
var result = 0.3 / 0.1;
if (Math.Abs(Math.Round(result) - result) < 0.0000001) 
{
    // Do something
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
var div = 5.4 / 0.8;
var divRound = Math.Round(div);

if (div == divRound)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Is integer");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Is Float");
}
```

Comment: Ouch! https://dotnetfiddle.net/mqIk4t I'll leave it to you to figure out why your answer does not really work reliably (pay attention to the numbers i used in my dotnetfiddle)

Comment: @elgonzo nice counterexample

Answer (score -3):

I think the fastest way is:

```
var a = 5.4;
var b = 0.8;
var result = a / b;
var isInteger = result % 1 == 0;

if (isInteger)
{
    ....
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Ouch! https://dotnetfiddle.net/njvycy (feel free to experiment with other numbers for `a` and `b` that would yield whole numbers as the division result)

Comment: hmmm, unless I misunderstood the question, this method works just fine to determine if the result of the division is an integer, result % 1 will be always zero if the result is an integer non-zero otherwise, that is the tricky